# Loading a css file with media-width query ONLY on load.

Tags: css

I wan't to load the correct css file for any webpage based on the INITIAL window size.

I'm currently including files like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 1250px)" href="file1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 1251px) and (max-width: 1700px)" href="file2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 1701px)" href="file3.css">
```

This code loads the correct css on load, but it will also change according to screen resizes.

Is there a way native to CSS to prevent the responsize file change?

I can write a script to remove the unused queries once the initial CSS was loaded but I wanted to know if there's a more native way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) JS property specially created for this. Using matchmedia you can execute blocks of JavaScript only when a certain mediaquery condition is met. For example:

```
if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1250px)')){
  document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" 
                  href="file1.css">');
}
```